# Random "Keyset does not exist" in Azure web app

Tags: azure, x509certificate

1. I'm using Azure web app
2. I'm storing the bytes[] of my certificate in a Database
3. I'm initializing like this:

   ```
   var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
   ```
4. I'm "randomly" getting the error `Keyset does not exist`. It typically acts like this:

   - It works the first time
   - It doesn't work just after that ("Keyset does not exist")
   - If I wait (15-20 secs), it works again

What I've tried:

This:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

This:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

This:

```
using (certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)) 
{ 
    ...
}
```

Nothing works...

This error is driving me crazy, once again thanks to Azure, because it works fine in a local server

Comment: Should I try "Azure Key Vault" to solve this problem? and how?

Comment: Seems that a Singleton pattern will work. I will update with an answer if it works.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this? We sometimes experience the same issue with seemingly identical setup.

Comment: I too am seeing this issue, did you ever find a fix?

Comment: @DenisPitcher  It is a really weird issue. It sometimes triggers randomly but I never figured out the pattern or source of this.  What I gave the users is a Singleton so that when it is created, it never fails again... but if the Singleton is created with the bug, they have to clear it and create it again

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the certificate. You are storing the public part. In Windows the public key is not stored on the same location as the private key.

The private key is stored in the CertificateStore ( either on the User or on the Machine).

If you want to store the public + private part, then export it to Pfx/Pkcs12 with this:

```
var certBytes = cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, (string)null)
```

More info:

- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Best-X509Certificate2-Practices
- https://paulstovell.com/x509certificate2/

Comment: In my original post I didn't show how it is stored (step 2 of my original post): the pfx is uploaded and I get the bytes of the file through `Request.Files`, here: `byte[] certificateBytes = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream).ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);`

Comment: Try the following.

Instead of : new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

==> 
use the X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet

Comment: I will try... but as I said in the step 4 of my original post: `I'm "randomly" getting the error`.  I posted this on 2020 and in the past years it has occurred less, almost never.... I ended up doing a Singleton which I must reset if I get the error, and I reuse the object if I didn't get the error